Removing unwanted value properties from FHIR JSON output?
I am working on developing a .NET Core application where I create FHIR resources based on results from a database. However, when generating the JSON response for a FHIR bundle, I am getting an unwanted value structure in the output. I want to completely remove these value levels so that the JSON response looks like a standard FHIR response without nested value fields.
Current JSON output:
{
  "id": {
    "value": "bundle-example"
  },
  "type": {
    "value": "searchset"
  },
  "total": {
    "value": 5
  },
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": {
        "value": "http://example.org/fhir/Observation/8393939"
      },
      "resource": {
        "id": {
          "value": "8393939"
        },
        "status": {
          "value": "final"
        },
        "code": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": {
                "value": "http://loinc.org"
              },
              "code": {
                "value": "1988-5"
              },
              "display": {
                "value": "CRP"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
        // ... other fields
      }
    }
    // ... other entries
  ]
}


Desired JSON Structure:
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "bundle-example",
  "type": "searchset",
  "total": 5,
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "http://example.org/fhir/Observation/8393939",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Observation",
        "id": "8393939",
        "status": "final",
        "code": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://loinc.org",
              "code": "1988-5",
              "display": "CRP"
            }
          ]
        }
        // ... other fields
      }
    }
    // ... other entries
  ]
}


Here is the relevant code from my ObservationService class that is responsible for generating the FHIR bundle:
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FHIR.PoC.Data;

namespace FHIR.PoC.Service
{
    public class ObservationService
    {
        private readonly SpecimenRepository m_specimenRepository;

        public ObservationService(SpecimenRepository specimenRepository)
        {
            m_specimenRepository = specimenRepository;
        }

        public Bundle MapToObservations(DataTable dtDbResults, bool bIncludeSpecimen)
        {
            var bundle = new Bundle
            {
                Id = "bundle-example",
                Type = Bundle.BundleType.Searchset,
                Total = dtDbResults.Rows.Count,
                Entry = new List<Bundle.EntryComponent>()
            };

            foreach (DataRow drRow in dtDbResults.Rows)
            {
                var observation = new Observation
                {
                    Id = drRow["zissample_id"].ToString() ?? "null",
                    Status = drRow["ZISRESULTSTATUS_ID"].ToString() == "8000013" ? ObservationStatus.Final : ObservationStatus.Preliminary,
                    Code = new CodeableConcept
                    {
                        Coding = new List<Coding>
                        {
                            new Coding
                            {
                                System = "http://loinc.org",
                                Code = drRow["LOINC_CODE"] != DBNull.Value ? drRow["LOINC_CODE"].ToString() : null,
                                Display = drRow["MEASURE_CODE"] != DBNull.Value ? drRow["MEASURE_CODE"].ToString() : null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Subject = new ResourceReference($"Patient/{drRow["SOURCE_ID"].ToString()}"),
                    Effective = GetEffectiveDate(drRow),
                    Issued = drRow["FIRSTREPORTDATETIME"] != DBNull.Value ? (DateTimeOffset?)Convert.ToDateTime(drRow["FIRSTREPORTDATETIME"]) : null,
                    Performer = new List<ResourceReference>
                    {
                        new ResourceReference("Practitioner/VasteWaardeLabTrain")
                    },
                    Value = GetObservationValue(drRow)
                };

                ProcessReferenceRangeIfPresent(drRow, observation);

                if (bIncludeSpecimen)
                {
                    ProcessSpecimen(drRow, observation);
                }

                bundle.Entry.Add(new Bundle.EntryComponent
                {
                    FullUrl = $"http://example.org/fhir/Observation/{observation.Id}",
                    Resource = observation
                });
            }

            return bundle;
        }

I am currently setting the properties of the FHIR resources, but the JSON response still contains a value structure. I've also tried assigning the values directly without wrapping them in an object, but the result remains the same.
How can I completely remove the value levels from the JSON response generated by my FHIR Observation resources? What should I adjust in the code to ensure the response has the correct structure, as shown in the desired JSON structure above?

Please show your PackageReference versions (inside your .csproj file)

I am guessing you are using a "regular" Json serializer, not a FHIR one.
These imports and objects.

using Hl7.Fhir.Serialization;
FhirJsonSerializer

simple example:
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using Hl7.Fhir.Serialization;

private static void PrettyPrintBundle(Bundle bundle)
{
    FhirJsonSerializer serializer = new FhirJsonSerializer(new SerializerSettings()
    {
        Pretty = true
    });

    Console.WriteLine(serializer.SerializeToString(bundle));
}

If you have a REST (webapi) service, you also have to "tweak" the serialization.
//     PackageReference Include="Hl7.Fhir.R4" Version="4.0.0"
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    /* services is a IServiceCollection */
    services.AddControllers(
        options =>
        {
        })
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        /* below is needed to accept R4 FHIR object payloads */
        ICollection<JsonConverter> fhirConverters = options.JsonSerializerOptions.ForFhir().Converters;
        foreach (JsonConverter fhirConverter in fhirConverters)
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(fhirConverter);
        }

    });

